# Why is Rails update action redirecting to default_locale only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, rails-i18n

In my multilingual Rails app I have a `ProfilesController`. I am using a GET variable `section` to split the view into different tabs. I am also storing that variable in a `session`, so that it will be remembered across requests.

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :signed_in_user
  before_action :find_profile
  before_action :set_section, :only => [:show, :edit]

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @profile.update_attributes(profile_params)
      flash[:success] = t('profiles.flash_messages.profile_updated')
      redirect_to edit_profile_path(:section => session[:section])
    else
      @title = t("views.#{session[:section]}")
      render :edit
    end
  end

private

def find_profile
  @profile = current_user.profile
end

def set_section
  section = Profile::SECTIONS.include?(params[:section]) ? params[:section] : Profile::SECTIONS[0]
  session[:section] = section
end
```

What I don't understand is why my `update` action constantly redirects to the `default_locale` rather than the locale the user chose and therefore stored in the session.

Can anybody tell me what I am missing here?

This is an excerpt of my `routes.rb` file: (Please note that I am using a *singular* resource here since each user can have only one profile)

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  scope '(:locale)' do

    resource  :membership

    ...

    get 'change_locale', :to => 'locales#change_locale'

  end

end
```

---

**Update:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :set_locale

  protected

  def set_locale
    if params[:locale]
      if I18n.available_locales.include?(params[:locale].to_sym)
        I18n.locale = session[:locale] || params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
      end
    end
  end

  def default_url_options
    { :locale => I18n.locale }
  end

end
```

Comment: could you show where locale sets?

Comment: @SergeyKutsko: Just updated my question.

Comment: updated. don't forget up me)

Comment: where you set and change session[:locale]? updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
redirect_to edit_profile_path(:section => session[:section], :locale => I18n.locale)
```

or

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_locale

  def default_url_options(options={})
    { locale: I18n.locale }
  end

protected
  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = (session[:locale] || params[:locale]).to_s.downcase.presence || I18n.default_locale
  end
end
```

this will help.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't do it either, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for changing your code again, but it's still not working :-(

Comment: Yes, that did it! The `set_locale` function was the key. I don't even need to pass the `locale` inside `edit_profile_path` anymore. It even works without it! Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set `default_url_options`:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def default_url_options(options={})
  { :locale => ((I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale) ? nil : I18n.locale) }
end
```

Comment: Thanks but I think I have it already. I posted my ApplicationController above to update my question.